# Bijection from ordered pairs of $[0,n]$

Tags: functions

I am looking for a simple expression to convert ordered pairs from  $[0,n]$ to the first smallest subset of $\mathbb N$.
For example if $n = 3$:

$$ (0, 1) \rightarrow 0$$
$$ (0, 2) \rightarrow 1$$
$$ (0, 3) \rightarrow 2$$
$$ (1, 2) \rightarrow 3$$
$$ (1, 3) \rightarrow 4$$
$$ (2, 3) \rightarrow 5$$

What could be an explicit formula for that?

To rephrase, I am looking for a formula $f_n(i, j)$ where $0 \le i < j \le n$ such that $0 \le f_n(i, j) < \left ( ^{n}_{2}\right )$ and $f_n$ is bijective. I would also like if possible the inverse bijection to retrieve $i$ and $j$ from an image of $f_n$.

The values of the function do not matter as long as the set of values is the same.

[Cantor pairing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) are not applicable here because the bijection is not infinite.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: I added the link in the question to state that it does not help. But thank you for trying.

Comment: The infiniteness of the bijection is usually not a problem; if you restrict the inputs to integers not exceeding $n$, it'll work quite nicely. But you're right in thinking I overlooked the "ordered" part of your requirements; it'd require one extra tweak before being usable directly.

Comment: What's wrong with the Cantor pairing function? The bijection _is_ infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are lazy, a simple adaptation of the [Cantor Pairing Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function) $\pi$ works quite well:

$$f(x,y):=\pi(x,y-x-1) = \frac{1}{2}y(y+1) - x - 1$$

As a bonus, it doesn't depend on $n$, so the same mapping can be extended to any $n$, without changing the resulting values.

Going backwards is quite easy too. Since $\frac{1}{2}y(y+1)-x-1 = \frac{1}{2}(y+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x - \frac{9}{8}$, if we want to "unpack" number $N$, we can simply calculate
$$y = \left\lceil \sqrt{2N + 9/4}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rceil$$
and then
$$x = \frac{1}{2}y(y+1)-1 - N$$

Comment: That would be awesome if the reverse bijection was so easy to compute.

Comment: ... and the reverse actually *is* quite easy to compute too; even though it might look scary at the first glance (see the updated answer for details).

Comment: This freaks me out but ok. I will have a look at how to implement a square root taking not too much calculus.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer What is the setting you're working in? I mean -- are you trying to implement it on computer; or on some device with restricted computing power; or perhaps doing it "by hand"? Since you're not actually interested in the square root, but (roughly speaking) only its integer part, you can avoid doing any non-integer arithmetics at all.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for asking, I am trying to do some low-level optimization of direct acyclic graph representations, and this was a problem I was stumbling on. How would you avoid computing the square root?

Comment: One (certainly not the most efficient) option is to preform simple binary search over the range $[0,n]$ for the value of $y$; if $\frac{1}{2}y(y+1)-1$ is smaller than $N$, the actual value lies in upper half; otherwise it lies in the bottom half of the interval. But do you really really need to pack everything into the shortest range possible? Combining the two numbers as $(n+1)x+y$ makes it *trivial* to extract both $x$ and $y$, while using just twice the minimum range.

Comment: Good spot. I did not think about that. Just one division to recover y.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bijection from your set of pairs $\{(i,j)\in \mathbb N^2|\,0\leq i<j\leq n\}$ to $\{(i,)\in\mathbb N^2|\,0\leq i\leq n-1,\, 0\leq j\leq n-1-i\}$, which are the first $n$ diagonals of the cantor pairing function, with $f:(i,j)\mapsto(i,j-i-1)$. ($f^{-1}:(i,j)\mapsto(i,i+j+1)$) Then, you can apply the cantor pairing function to $f(i,j)$ to obtain $k$ and retrieve the original $(i,j)$ with $f^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(k))$